# When I know the two points on an elliptic curve, and the two points satisfy the relationship: $Q=e \cdot P$, is it possible for me to solve for e

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, computational-number-theory

When I know the two points on an elliptic curve, and the two points satisfy the relationship: $Q=e \cdot P$, is it possible for me to solve for $e$.
The equation of the curve is: $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b \pmod p$, while
$e$ is a $32$-bit integer.

Comment: If e is 32 bit integer, e <2^32 you can solve it in O(2^16), which is very efficient on a computer.

Comment: This question is better suited to crypto.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 10):

Adding on a bit to David Speyer's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/462561), the **elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem** (ECDLP) has been studied intensively since the 1980s, and in addition to commercial applications, there is a vast research industry that studies the problem and its applications in cryptography. As Speyer says, it is "believed to be hard", indeed the best known general *classical algorithms* take exponential time (which in your setting means a fractional power of $p$ or $e$), as opposed to various sub-exponential running time algorithms for factorization (used for RSA) or for solving the finite field discrete logarithm problem (find $e$ that solves $A\equiv B^e\bmod p$). However, there is a [*quantum algorithm* due to Shor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) that would solve the ECDLP in (practical) polynomial time if/when a sufficiently large quantum computer is built. If you want to find out about some of the algorithms that are used to solve the ECDLP, you might read about the [*babystep-giantstep method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) or [*Pollard's rho method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms), each of which (in your setting) has a run-time of roughly $\sqrt{p}\approx\sqrt{e}\approx2^{16}$, so would be quite feasible. In cryptographic applications, the $p$ and the $e$ are more like 200 to 1000 bits.

Answer (score 6):

This is called the "[elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography#Elliptic_curve_theory)". It is believed to be hard, and several commercial cryptographic schemes are based on this belief.